# Trying to combine an image with a Plot

Tags: graphics, image

I've got this picture:

[image: JuliaSet]

The image has a resolution of 2001x2001. The left most pixel has an x-value of -2, and the right most pixel has an x-value of 2. Same goes for the y-values. Now I am trying to load this image into *Mathematica* and get it on the right scale inside a graphics environment. I've tried using inset like this:

```
julia = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLMXG.png"];
Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], 
    Inset[julia, Center, Center, 4]}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

This still gives a little blue border around some sides, giving me the impression that it is not centered properly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I changed `Julia` to `julia`. It's a good habit to avoid starting variable names with capital letters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Inset` is not suitable for reliable and *precise* positioning.  Use [`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Raster.html) to include bitmap data in an image.  It lets you specify the coordinates of the corners:

```
Graphics[
 Raster[ImageData[julia], {{-2, -2}, {2, 2}}],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
]
```

[image]

Note: the `Graphics` `Method` option I used is undocumented, so it might change in the future.  It is used by functions like `DensityPlot` to make sure the grid lines are not obscured by other graphics elements.

Comment: @Öskå What version do you have?  I tried with [8 and 9](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4idr9wb51igaib9/Screenshot%202014-06-16%2010.30.06.png).

Comment: @Öskå So is that the leftmost pixel or the leftmost black pixel?